# Equivalence of matrix norms

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces, matrix-norms

The equivalence of vector norms on finite dimensional spaces  immediately implies that all **induced** matrix norms are equivalent.

However, for matrix norms (like Frobenius norm, Nuclear norm) that are **not** induced by a vector norm, one proves equivalence on a case by case basis.

Hence my question is, **can I say all matrix norms, induced or not, are equivalent ?** If so how do I justify it in general ?

Comment: The space of matrices is finite, isn't it?

Comment: @user251257: True. But the proof for vector norms uses the fact that $\mathbb{R}^n$ is compact. Is the answer as trivial as saying $\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ has dimension $n^2$ and $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$ is compact ?

Comment: $\mathbb R^n$ isn't compact. From vector space perspective $\mathbb R^{n\times n}$ is the "same" as $\mathbb R^{nn}$.

Comment: @user251257: Of course, my mistake. I ought to have said unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is compact.

Comment: All norms on $R^m$ are equivalent. Induction on $m$ can be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [wiki article on matrix norms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm) summarizes it very well:

> In mathematics, a matrix norm is a vector norm in a vector space whose elements (vectors) are matrices (of given dimensions).

So a *matrix* norm is always a *vector* norm - on the (vector) space of $n\times n$ matrices. Since this space is finite dimensional, all vector norms on it are equivalent. And because equivalence of vector norms is the same condition as equivalence of matrix norms, all matrix norms are equivalent too.

---

You say,

> However, for matrix norms (like Frobenius norm, Nuclear norm) that are not induced by a vector norm, one proves equivalence on a case by case basis.

Which is true if you want to *compute* good estimates on the coefficients $$a\|\cdot\|_{\alpha}\le\|\cdot\|_{\beta}\le b\|\cdot\|_{\alpha}.$$

But since any matrix norm - induced or not - satisfies the *properties* of a vector norm, the theorem of vector norm equivalence (asserting only *existence* of the coefficients) applies. The *describing properties* imply equivalence (in finite dimensions), not the particular norm definition.